# Getting Error while I emulates app in newer versions of android

Tags: android, json, android-tablelayout

When I run my app in android 2.3, it works fine while as in newer version like 4.2.2, 4.4.4 it's showing error. My app is getting Json data and displaying it as table view.So please help me get out of this.Below is all necessary codes.

MainActivity.java

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View view) 
          {
             String result = null;
            InputStream is = null;

            try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/selectall.php");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                 //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            //convert response to string
            try
            {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result=sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            //parse json data
            try
            {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


            TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();




               int flag=1;

            for(int i=-1;i<jArray.length()-1;i++)

                    {




                            TableRow tr=new TableRow(MainActivity.this);

                            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));




                            if(flag==1)
                            {

                                TextView b6=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                 b6.setText("ID");
                                 b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 b6.setTextSize(15);
                                 tr.addView(b6);


                                TextView b19=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                 b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                 b19.setTextSize(15);
                                 b19.setText("Name");
                                 b19.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 tr.addView(b19);

                               TextView b29=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                             b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                 b29.setText("no");
                                 b29.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                 b29.setTextSize(15);
                                 tr.addView(b29);


                             tv.addView(tr);

                                 final View vline = new View(MainActivity.this);
                                      vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));
                                      vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);



                            tv.addView(vline);
                            flag=0;


                            }

                            else
                            {



                                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("f1")+
                                          ", Username: "+json_data.getString("f2")+
                                          ", No: "+json_data.getInt("f3"));




                        TextView b=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                            String stime=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("f1"));
                              b.setText(stime);
                            b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            b.setTextSize(15);
                            tr.addView(b);


                           TextView b1=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                            b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                            b1.setTextSize(15);
                            String stime1=json_data.getString("f2");
                             b1.setText(stime1);
                            b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            tr.addView(b1);

                          TextView b2=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                         b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                            String stime2=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("f3"));
                            b2.setText(stime2);
                            b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            b2.setTextSize(15);
                            tr.addView(b2);

                              tv.addView(tr);


                    final View vline1 = new View(MainActivity.this);
                  vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
                  vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                  tv.addView(vline1);       


                            }

                   }



            }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




       }
       });
}
```

LogCat:

```
12-28 11:57:38.076: D/OpenGLRenderer(1681): Render dirty regions requested: true
12-28 11:57:38.080: D/(1681): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa5d721c0, tid 1681
12-28 11:57:38.180: D/Atlas(1681): Validating map...
12-28 11:57:38.320: D/libEGL(1681): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
12-28 11:57:38.321: D/(1681): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa5d72320, tid 1696
12-28 11:57:38.355: D/libEGL(1681): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
12-28 11:57:38.374: D/libEGL(1681): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
12-28 11:57:38.391: I/OpenGLRenderer(1681): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-28 11:57:38.440: D/OpenGLRenderer(1681): Enabling debug mode 0
12-28 11:57:38.485: W/EGL_genymotion(1681): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-28 11:57:38.485: W/OpenGLRenderer(1681): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5d260c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-28 11:57:48.394: E/log_tag(1681): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-28 11:57:48.396: E/log_tag(1681): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
12-28 11:57:48.397: D/AndroidRuntime(1681): Shutting down VM
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): Process: com.dbselect.dbselect, PID: 1681
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at com.dbselect.dbselect.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-28 11:57:48.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dbselect.dbselect.MainActivity" >

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


 <ScrollView
         android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true" >


    <TableLayout 

    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true">


</TableLayout>


   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: because in newer version ( 4+ ) you can't do any internet communicator in UI thread, you must use thread like AsyncTask to do network IO

Comment: OK, mean I need to use doInBackground. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: you can use basichandler for your app.